# How to access response status codes from backend to frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

backend code: this code is right i guess because it gives error message correct on postman.

```
const userExist = await User.findOne({email:email})
        if(userExist){
             return res.status(422).send({error:"email is same"});
        }else if( password != cpassword){
            return res.status(422).send({error:"password not same"});
        }else{
            const user = new User({username,email,password,cpassword});
            await user.save();
             res.status(200).send({message:"done"});
            
        }
```

Frontend code:

```
const res = await fetch("/signup",{
  method:"POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username, email, password, cpassword
  })
});

const data = await res.json();
console.log(data);
if(data.status === 422){
  window.alert("Invalid Registration");
  console.log("Invalid Registration");
}
else{
  window.alert("Registration");
  console.log("Registration");

  history.push("/login");
}
```

Console.log(data) does not show status only shows error message, how to access error status code or messages in react.js here. And data.status shows undefined in react in above code.

Comment: You should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: check this `console.log(res.status)`

Answer (score 2):

The status code is the [status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status) property on the response object. You need to check the status code (or the [ok flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok)) before calling `response.json()`.

**Example:**

```
fetch(`${baseUrl}/signup `, {
   method:"POST",
   headers: {
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({
    username, email, password, password
   })
})
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.status); // Will show you the status
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then(// ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do, with `async await` more cleaner approach as per your question, you can avoid callback hell with `.then()`

```
const res = await fetch("/signup",{
  method:"POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username, email, password, cpassword
  })
});
```

with this,

```
console.log(res.status)
const status = res.status;

if(status.OK){  
  window.alert("Registration");
  console.log("Registration");

  history.push("/login");
}
else{
  window.alert("Invalid Registration");
  console.log("Invalid Registration");
}
```